# Raspberry Pi 4 SD Card reader rejects SD cards intermittently

Tags: sd-card

I have a Raspberry Pi 4. It worked up until a week ago, then upon a regular reboot, it gives me -110 error. But not always, sometimes it even boots to desktop. I even tried other SD Cards, including a new in box SanDisc.
Without an SD Card, it always gives me a screen indicating it can't find an SD Card. I assume the SD Card reader is defective, even though there's no visibile damage. I tried cleaning it with isopropyl and canned air, but there's no result. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: is booting from USB an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Didn't know that was possible. I'll look into it, thanks